# Не могу добавить Box Collider 2D

Tags: unity3d

Не могу добавить  Box Collider 2D к модели. Модель 3D (отображается 2D, просто нужны тени), сама игра в 2D. Шкала масштабирования модели 50. Саи коллайдер по Х растягивается, а по Y нет. (Circle Collider работает) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> The collider did not create any collision shapes as they all failed
>   verification. This could be because they were deemed too small or the
>   vertices were too close. Vertices can also become close under certain
>   rotations or very small scaling.

Comment: Есть подозрения, что Вы повернули GameObject таким образом, что ось Oy стала перпендикулярна экрану.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов да Y=-90 и Z=90, после блендера развернул модель

Comment: Это решило Вашу проблему?

Comment: Развернул модель -90 x / 0 y / 0 z    Тоже не добавляет коллайдер

Comment: Не решило, просто сказал, что модель была повернута

Comment: Это что за размер такое по `Y`?

Answer (score 1):

Развернул в blender модель набок, чтобы внутри движка ничего не переворачивать по X, Z - Box Collider 2D создается и хорошо редактируется.